# Define compile dependencies in gradle that dont get packaged

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to configure gradle to use `lombok` to compile my project but I don't want the classes appearing in my jar. On the other side I need the `mysql-connector` dependency packages in the jar, but it's not needed for compiling. This is my build.gradle file:

```
group 'de.albritter'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
    jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'de.albritter.main.Main'
    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.16.8'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.39'

}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.39'
        classpath group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.16.8'
    }
}
```

I've seen some solutions using `compileOnly` but if i try to use it I just gete an error that this method is not known.
My gradle version is 2.9

How do I tell gradle that I don't need `lombok` in my jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is variously known as `compileOnly` or in the maven world, `provided` dependency. The `compileOnly` configuration was [introduced in gradle in version 2.12](http://gradle.org/blog/compile-only-dependencies/). I would strongly recommend moving to the latest version of gradle (2.14 at the time of writing this).

If you need to stick to the older version, there are some workarounds you can find by looking for "gradle provided dependency". One way to do this is to declare your own configuration, lets call it provided and adding its dependencies to compile time classpath. So in your build.gradle:

```
configurations{
    provided
}

sourceSets {
    main.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    test.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    test.runtimeClasspath += configurations.provided
}

dependencies {
    ...
    provided 'group:module:version'
    ...
}
```

Or alternatively you can use the [prodeps](https://github.com/spring-projects/gradle-plugins/tree/master/propdeps-plugin) plugin which does most of this work for you.